# Using Enums inside EF queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework, enums

I have following query (EF5, .NET4.5):

```
from p in repository
select new Person() {
    Name = p.Name, 
    Birthday = p.Birthday,
    MyEnumValue = MyEnum.Value1
};
```

where *MyEnumValue* is **enum** defined like:

```
public enum MyEnum : byte
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2
}
```

At runtime this code causing the exception:

*The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Byte' type to the 'MyApp.Domain.Models.MyEnum' type is not valid.*

But if I change enum definition to

```
public enum MyEnum { ... }
```

all works fine.

Is it possible to fix exception don't change MyEnum to int? (and without additional byte property :) )

Comment: What is the corresponding column in the database? Is it CodeFirst?

Comment: It's DB-First. There is not corresponding column for MyEnumValue. I gets 'p' object (type doesn't matter) from the database and build a new Person object (Person and MyEnum types are not included into the Model).

Comment: I cannot repro this. I did `    public enum TestEnum : byte { Test };

    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TestEnum EnumValue { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new Entities())
            {
                var c = ctx.Countries.Select(a => new Test { Name = a.CountryName, EnumValue = TestEnum.Test });
                Console.Write(c != null);
            }
        }
    }`. What am I missing?

Comment: This is DB First. There is not corresponding column for MyEnumValue and no corresponding table for Person. I gets 'p' object (type doesn't matter) from the database and create a new instance of the Person object. Person and MyEnum types are not included into the Database Model and even more - defined in other assembly.

Comment: what does the `repository` return? I have an impression that the issue is not in the projection but in the mapping and the query. Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: This what happens when you repurpose a .FirstOrDefault() query... Anyways even after forcing evaluation I see no exception.

Comment: You forgot to run the query: c.ToList(). Repository returns DbSet<> from context (same as ctx.Countries in your example).

Comment: Our conversation gave me an idea. I using MySQL for this code and now I checked it against MSSQL. And it works. Thanks. Looks like MySQL Connector bug.

Comment: I am glad that you found the root cause. I think you should update the question and post your comment as anwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is MySQL .NET Connector bug. So there is one option only - make workaround and wait for next release.

Answer (score -2):

Try cast like this :

```
from p in repository
select new Person() {
    Name = p.Name, 
    Birthday = p.Birthday,
    MyEnumValue  = (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), MyEnum.Value1, true)
};
```

if "MyEnumValue " field of "Person" is byte so cast as byte...

Comment: This will not compile. And even with "MyEnum.Value1.ToString(), true" it will not work. LINQ to Entities not support Enum.Parse()

Comment: Why would you hack like this? EF5 on .NET Framework 4.5 has support for enums and no hacking should be necessary.

Comment: should be ;) But code in question above working when enum is int32 only.